# Wrap if long not working in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, format

I have custom settings for my android projects.

I cannot get my code to wrap, whether I use `wrap if long` or `always wrap`.

I have included screenshots.

I have used the settings for the android xml, the xml, the java, the margin.

[image: AndroidXmlWrapping]

[image: xmlWrap][image: JavaWrapping]

**The Margin:**
[image: MarginWrap]

**It still extends past the margin line and does not wrap.** 
[image: NotWrappingExample]

It's frustrating, as I want to be able to view all the code without using the scrollbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out. It doesn't seem to automatically format as being typed on on save (there may be a format on save option somewhere).
Using reformat code:

`Crt+Alt+L`

Or go to `Code` in the menu bar, find `Reformat Code` in the drop down list as shown in the image.

[image: reformatCode]